# Оптимизация задачи на графы

Tags: c++, графы

Вот условие, нужно оптимальное решение задачи!
[image]

Мое решение проходит 19 тестов из 20. Могу привести код если нужен. Тесты тоже все есть, могу скинуть. Я свою ошибку знаю и знаю как ее исправить, но если я ее исправлю то сложность возрастет порядка n!, что будет не допустимо в данном случае.
Общий алгоритм выглядит так:

```
0) считываю граф и переориентирую его    
1) выбираю все вершины истоки(вершины в которые не входит ни одно ребро)
2) запускаю dfs от каждого истока, запуск - dfs(int x, int day) - для истока day = 0
      2.1) проверяю на наличие цикла
      2.2) в массив для каждой вершину записываю самый длинный путь = day
      2.3) для смежной, закрытой, не помеченной вершины, запуск-dfs(v[x][i], day + 1) 
3) Если есть цикл то вывожу -1 и выхожу
4) иначе произвожу подсчет дней. Вот здесь и возникает ошибка, допустим входные данные
    4 2             тогда моя программа распределит вершины в след. порядке
    0                1 день - 1 2
    0                2 день - 3 
    0                3 день - 4  
    1 3              хотя можно управиться и за 2 дня
т.е. важен порядок выбора вершин с одинаковым приоритетом. Получается нужна перебирать набор вершин и подсчитывать кол-во дней для каждой новой генерации и выбирать минимум, что я не в состоянии сделать из - за ограничения времени
```

Вот код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#define N 20

using namespace std;

typedef vector<int> graph;
vector<graph> v(N), g(N);
int n, m, col[N], days[N];
bool used[N], f = true, istok[N], used2[N];

void dfs ( int x, int day )
{
     days[x] = day;
     used[x] = true;     
     col[x] = 1; // open vertex
     for (int i = 0; i < v[x].size(); i++)
         if ( !used[v[x][i]] )            
            dfs(v[x][i], day + 1);           
         else
         if ( col[v[x][i]] == 1 ) // Cycle
         {
            f = false;
            return;
         }
         else  
             if ( day + 1 > days[v[x][i]] ) // new way is longer than old one
                dfs(v[x][i], day + 1);
     col[x] = 2; // close vertex
}

bool good ( int x )
{
     for (int i = 0; i < g[x].size(); i++)
         if ( !used[g[x][i]] )
            return false;
     return !used[x];    
}

int main()
{
    freopen("a.in", "r", stdin);
    freopen("a.out", "w", stdout);

    //vvod & init
    int k, x, l = 0;
    cin >> n >> m;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> k;
        if ( k == 0 )
           istok[i] = true; // array of sources
        for (int j = 0; j < k; j++)
        {
            cin >> x;
            x--;
            v[x].push_back(i);    
            g[i].push_back(x);       
        }  
        used[i] = false;    
    }

    //solve
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        if ( istok[i] )
             dfs(i, 0);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)   
    { 
        if ( !used[i] )
             f = false;   
        used[i] = false;
        used2[i] = false;
    }       

    //output   
    if ( !f )
    {
         cout << -1;
         return 0;
    }    

    int s = 0, day = 0;
    f = true;
    while (f) {
        f = false;
        x = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) 
            if ( days[j] <= day && x < m && good(j) )
            {
                 used2[j] = true;
                 f = true;
                 x++;
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            used[j] = used2[j];
        day++;
    }
    cout << day - 1;
    return 0;    
}
```

Comment: Что-то ваше описание алгоритма в 4-м пункте не сходится с кодом. Программа найдет максимальный маршрут = 2 дня, как и ожидалось.

Comment: нет она вернет 3 дня..! т.к. в цикле for (int j = 0; j < n; j++), сначала будет j = 0, j = 1 он и выбирет 2 эти работы! потом выйдет из цикла, обнулит кол-во выполненных работ(x = 0) , потом опять найдет работу (j = 2), (j = 3) не будет выполнено т.к. good(3) вернет false, т.к. 2 только на этом этапе выполняется.  и потом на 3 дне выберет (j = 3). получится 3 дня

Comment: Так мы не придем к результату. Задача решается поиском максимального пути в ориентированном графе. Поиск должен производится в глубину и обрываться при превышении длины пути или зацикливании, иначе возвращать максимальный путь. 
У вас в коде зачем-то создается два графа и не один из них не строится на корне (используется дополнительный массив `istok`). Реализован поиск в глубину, но используется много ненужных флагов. Например `used` не нужен и к тому же может привести к ошибочным результатам. `col` вполне может принимать два значения.